# LinkedIn - OAuth2 - retrieve list of all connections

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How can I retrieve all connections of a profile? The user is logged in, I can successfully retrieve the profile with https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json but I don't know how to get all connections of a profile.

- solution 1 (does not work!): I've found out, that it could be retrieved with https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?modified=new but that needs, as far as I found out, the r_network scope. But I can't even add this scope to my app as the appended picture shows. And just adding the scope to my request does not work, as I get a "Access to connections denied" response...

[image]

**Questions:**

- So how can I retrieve a list of all connections?
- how can I add r_network scope to my app?

Answer (score 1):

The `r_network` scope recently changed to be a LinkedIn partner-only permission.  You can apply for access to their partnership program here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the reason. And all currently available code examples and tutorials do not respect that fact yet